# Is there a simple way to convert any value direct to String in production code?

Tags: apex, fields, string, dynamic

When I do a System.debug(whatever), SFDC doesn't care whether whatever is a String, a Date, a Datetime, a Boolean, etc... it just makes a string of it and dumps it in the log.

But in the following code:

```
    private static String transverse  (Case countryCase, String csvFieldName) {
SObject      currentSObject = countryCase;
String       fieldPath      = csvFieldName;

while (fieldPath.contains('.'))
{
    List<String> pathPartList   = fieldPath.split ('[.]', 2);

                 currentSObject = (SObject) currentSObject.getSobject(pathPartList[0]);
                 fieldPath      = pathPartList[1];
}

return (String) currentSObject.get(fieldPath);
```

SFDC will complain if the value is a Boolean, Date, Datetime, or maybe others(?).

I imagine that with some mapping and other complexity, I could first check the field type for currentSObject.get(fieldPath) and do some transformation/formatting before returning it... but that seems to be over-complicating things.

Is there any way to just dumping the value as if I were doing a System.debug()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) has several static utility methods to transform a value into its string representation, like this:

```
String.valueOf(variableName);
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting all of it together:

```
public static String toString(Object input) {
    if (input instanceof Date) {
        return ((Date) input).format();
    } else if (input instanceof Datetime) {
        return ((Datetime) input).format();
    } else if (input instanceof Decimal) {
        return ((Decimal) input).toPlainString();
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I found that with `String.valueOf` it would return scientific notation for a large decimal value... which I didn't like (caused issues for me) -- so I implemented the following code:

```
public static String getStringValue (Object theObj) {
    String strValue = String.valueOf( theObj );
    if ( theObj instanceof Decimal ) strValue = ((Decimal)theObj).toPlainString(); // Prevent scientific notation
    return strValue;
}
```

Thought I would share in case this helps someone else in the future.